# Hide all table row with bgcolor

Tags: javascript, css, hide

I've got a long table of which some of them has a bgcolor attribute:

```
<tr bgcolor="#EAE5C2">
```

I want to hide this rows with js.
Is there any way to target only this rows and Possibly apply a display: none; css?

Comment: Refer below link:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in CSS you can use an attribute selector

```
tr[bgcolor] { display: none }
```

otherwise in Javascript select all the elements via `document.querySelectorAll('tr[bgcolor]')`

e.g.

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr[bgcolor]').forEach(
  (r) => r.style.display = 'none';
);
```

Comment: thanks, tr[bgcolor="#EAE5C2"] { display: none } do the trick